# Enforce Type for foreach loop in Python?

Tags: python

I am rather new to Python but I do have a degree in computer science so it's just a matter of learning the quirks of this language.

Got the following function:

```
@staticmethod
def count_class_instance_based_on_attribute_value(data, attribute, attribute_value, classification):
    count = 0
    for val in data:
        if val.get_attribute_value(attribute) == attribute_value:
            if val.m_Class == classification:
                count = count + 1
    return count
```

When I write in PyCharm I wanna of course make use of code completition and other intellisense like features. But when I do the for loop in that function, I cannot figure out how to enforce that `val` should be a specific type (or class) that I made so I can be sure that the `get_attribute_value()` function can actually be called in the first place.

As things are now, I can just pray and hope.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: Python isn't type enforcing language. if you must you can check your `val` each loop for the `type` it should be...

Comment: OP should really use `isinstance` rather than `type`, @MooingRawr.

Comment: FWIW, we don't often use static methods in Python.

Comment: Python does not use static-time type checking. To check the type, you'd have to do it at runtime using `isinstance`. This, of course, won't help intellisense. However, one normally does not do this in Python.

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually PyCharm suggested I made that a static method, since it does not rely on "self" at all. So I just said "Okay I guess" Lol

Comment: SInce you already know how to code but are new to Python you should check out [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables), to get a quick summary of an important difference between Python's data model and the data model that you're familiar with from other languages. For a more in-depth look, see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay, I guess it can't be helped then. Just cool to know. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianDean yes he should, but that wasn't my point of my comment, I never really specify what OP should use to check what his `type` is, just that he can.

Comment: @MooingRawr Ah, okay. I thought you were saying the OP should use the `type` function since you were putting "type" in backticks.

Comment: This does raise the question however, if I was to do a for-each and wanted to call specific functions on the objects that I expect to find in that list, then how would that be standardised? It's a fairly normal thing to do in other languages like C#, Java and JavaScript. I suppose I could check for what type of object it is before I try, but that would be a long "if/else" attempt I guess.

Comment: I disagree: The `@staticmethod` decorator is not that rare. It does just what you thought: indicate that a class method does not require `self`. And your code is not all that bad - you want to count how many items in `data` are of some particular class and have some particular attribute values. That is just what it does.

Comment: @j08lue fair enough then. I wish whoever downvoted would tell me why they did so. Feels like a fairly legitimate question.

Comment: Generally, (but not always), the contents of a list should be homogeneous, i.e., all the base elements are of the same type. Processing heterogeneous lists gets messy. And if you expect that your list items will almost always be of the correct type it's simplest to assume that they _are_ all of the correct type, and use exception handling to deal with the oddball items. Exception handling in Python is very fast unless the exception is actually raised.

Comment: @PM2Ring Alright, thanks. I'll have to come to terms with that haha

Comment: @j08lue Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that use of `@staticmethod` should be avoided, just that we don't use static methods much in Python, compared to other languages. And if you have a class with a majority of static methods that can indicate that maybe you shouldn't even be using a class, or at least it may need some re-designing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `hasattr(val, 'get_attribute_value')` or catch an eventual `AttributeError` like so:

```
count = 0
for val in data:
    try:
        if val.get_attribute_value(attribute) == attribute_value:
            if val.m_Class == classification:
                count = count + 1
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

which is very pythonic.

But if you are after a very particular custom class, you could also check whether your `val` is an instance of your class, with `isintance(val, YourClass)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Considering the comment chain on my original question, it would appear that this is simply not something you do in Python. But this does technically answer the question :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly,

`if type(val) is [your_custom_type_or_class]:`

is how you would check the type in a conditional, obviously where `[your_custom_type_or_class]` is your actual type you are looking for. Just like:

`if type(val) is str:`

would be checking for a string.

Comment: So then you'd never cast it, but just assume the function is there if it passes the conditional? My gripe was that I could not auto-complete that function call while I write, because to PyCharm ``val`` is just an object.

Comment: I'm sorry, in terms of auto-completion I have no good advice to offer.